# How can I manipulate the output of Information?

Tags: output-formatting, output

If I type

```
Information[ProductLog]
```

I see

[image: Information[ProductLog]]

If I type

```
Framed[Information[ProductLog]]
```

I see

[image: Framed[Information[ProductLog]]]

This is expected, though not desired, because `Information` prints its output, rater than returning it.  However, I want to get access to the text of the description, or the boxes of the description, or something, to, e.g., put the descriptions of functions in columns or rows.  How do I do things like this?

Comment: The output cells are created by `CellPrint`.  You can capture the cell expressions with `Block[{CellPrint = Sow},
 Reap@Information[ProductLog]
 ]`, but I'm not sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the `"PlaintextUsage"` or `"TypesetUsage"`property of [`WolframLanguageData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html).

```
WolframLanguageData["ProductLog", "PlaintextUsage"]
```

or

```
WolframLanguageData[ToString@ProductLog, "PlaintextUsage"]
```

gives

> ```
> "ProductLog[z] gives the principal solution for w in z\[LongEqual]we^w. ProductLog[k, z] gives the k^th solution."
> ```

Note the escapes like `"\[LongEqual]"` will evaluate to their symbol in strings in Mathematica/Wolfram Language.

For typeset lines then

```
WolframLanguageData["ProductLog", "TypesetUsage"][[1, 1]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler method to get the usage messages for further manipulation is to use `MessageName[symbol, "usage"]`:

```
MessageName[ProductLog, "usage"]
```

which already yields a typeset version, similar to what is produced by `Information[]`.

And of course, `Attributes[symbol]` will return `symbol`'s associated attributes.